# Python search function to find a word in a string

Tags: python, function

```
def search(text, word):
    if word in text:
        print("Word found")
    else:
        print("Word not found")

text = str(input())
word = str(input())

print(search(text,word))
```

This code returns the following:

```
"Word found \
none"
```

When I use this entry:

```
"This is some sample text" \
"some"
```

The desired output would be: `"Word found"`

Comment: You function `search` doesn't explicitly return a value, so it returns `None`. What do you want to return?

Comment: Either 'word found' or ' word not found'. However the print function should output that for me right?

Comment: Yes, the print function prints that out, but it doesn't return it from the function. If you want the function to return a value than use something like `return 'word found'`

Comment: The search function already prints the message.  You don't need to call print at the main level.

Comment: Genius! Thank you, code works now. I'm going to do some more learning around this as I don't yet fully understand.

Comment: Thank you for linking this. Now I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. You aren’t returning a value in your function.

```
def search(text, word):
    if word in text:
        print("Word found")
        return word
    else:
        return "Word not found"

text = str(input())
word = str(input())

print(search(text,word))
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but the two return statements return different things, which is bad design. OP said the output should be just `Word found`, so remove the `return word` and just do `return "Word found"` instead.

Comment: Good catch! My bad!